# post array of objects through ajax call to web method return null

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

trying to post array of objects to post method but it null

```
data="{"ParamObjArr":[{"RegistrationId":"1033","LanguageCode":"en"},{"RegistrationId":"1033","LanguageCode":"en"}]}"
```

client side:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PostNewUserEducation", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            //
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
          //
        }
    });
```

Code behind:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> PostNewUserEducation(Dictionary<string,string> ParamObjArr)
    {
            string uriAction = "http://2525/api/NewUser";
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uriAction, ParamObjArr);
    }
```

in web method lstUserEducation is null, how to receive array of object in dictionary

Comment: Thar be some funky quotations in ye code.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create Class, which has property of list type of another

Create 2 class as below:

```
public class ParamObjArr
    {
        public string RegistrationId { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<ParamObjArr> ParamObjArr { get; set; }
    }
```

And Then Accept in your action.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> PostNewUserEducation(RootObject getData)
        {
            string uriAction = "http://2525/api/NewUser";
             HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uriAction, getData);
        }
```

Comment: if i update data and remove lstUserEducation   ,action method parameter that should accept ? @Amit Kumer

Comment: `data="{"ParamObjArr":[{"RegistrationId":"1033","LanguageCode":"en"},{"RegistrationId":"1033","LanguageCode":"en"}]}"` @Amit Kumer